# Threads Executor non blocking list

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

I have a class that iterates through a list of links. For each link I want to do a treatment. So I have to create a thread for each link.

Here is the code (Main):

```
ThreadProcessing  tp;
for(int i = 0; i < listUrl.size(); i++)
{
    tp.add(string_url);
}
```

For the ThreadProcessing class, I have to use the Executor interface.
The point is : I have to create a pool of 30 threads. ThreadP class contains a list of non-blocking threads (it can contain more than 30 threads of course). You can add as many threads as you want and the class will be responsible to perform all these threads.

So that's what I tried to do (it does not work).The ThreadProcessing class :

```
public class ThreadProcessing {
    List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
    ExecutorService pool;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
    }

    public void add(String url)
    {   
        runnables.add(createRunnable(url));
        executeRunnables(pool, runnables);
    }

    public static void executeRunnables(final ExecutorService service, List<Runnable> runnables){
        for(Runnable r : runnables){
            service.execute(r);
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }

    private Runnable createRunnable(final String url){

        Runnable getContentFromURL = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //My treatment with url
            }
        };
        return getContentFromURL;
    }
}
```

I hope I have not been too vague in my explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void add( String url) {
    Runnable job = createRunnable(url); 
    runnables.add( job);
    pool.execute( job);
}
```

Also, do not shut the pool down unless you are finished submitting/adding jobs. Of course, in this example, you don't really need the runnables List.

Comment: thank you for your response, so I have to shutdown the pool when I have iterate all of the urls?

Comment: the problem in your code is that you add a URLRunnable to your list, then submit all the runnables from the list to the pool. Next run in the loop, you submit all jobs again, plus one more. You just have to submit each runnable one time. Since the pool has its own list of runnables, you do not have to keep them in your list. Just send them to the pool and shut it down afterwards. The pool will only be finished executing after `awaitTermination`. Technically, you do not have to shut it down and wait for finish, but sometimes you want to know when that time has come.

Comment: So, if I delete my method called "executeRunnables", and,  in my method called "add" I put the code given by Ralf H, it will work right?

Comment: right, and if you want to know when processing has finished, call `shutdown`, followed by `awaitTermination` after you submitted all jobs

Comment: ok thank you. But I have a question : if I set a pool of 20 threads and then I add a new thread to my list of runnables, how it will happen?

Comment: You do not add a thread to your runnables. They are different. Threads execute runnables. A lot of question here result from that confusion. 
So if there is another runnable, submit it to the pool. Unless you already shut it down, in which case you must create another pool.

Comment: But if I don't have shutdown the pool and I add a new runnable in the pool (and the pool is currently full), what happens?

Comment: The pool has a limited number of threads (which is OK since the number of logical cores is limited, too), but – if you use Executors.newFixedThreadPool – an unlimited job queue, an instance of `BlockingQueue`. When you submit jobs, they will be added to the queue and processes in the order in which they arrive. Refer to JavaDoc or http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Comment: So, I have to take the code proposed by Pierre Vakimshaar ? Or it is done automatically?

Comment: Use any code you like. But read the docs and the tutorial examples I gave in the last comment. A ThreadPool will queue its jobs before executing. The next available worker thread will always take the first job in the queue. If you use queues with limited capacity, the pool will add worker threads up to the specified maximum when the queue fills up. Using too many threads (over a certain amount depending on wour hardware) will give no performance benefit.

Comment: Yes I am reading your link. I can read that :                                                      " In above program, we are creating fixed size thread pool of 5 worker threads. Then we are submitting 10 jobs to this pool, since the pool size is 5, it will start working on 5 jobs and other jobs will be in wait state, as soon as one of the job is finished, another job from the wait queue will be picked up by worker thread and get’s executed."                                                                       So I think it's good in my situation !

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public void main() {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

    BlockingQueue<String> urls = 
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(listUrl.size(), false, listUrl);
    LinkedList<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; ++i) {
        futures.add(es.submit(new URLRunnable(urls)));
    }

    // Wait for all the futures to return
    for(Future<?> f : futures) {
        f.get();
    }
}

public class URLRunnable() implements Runnable() {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> urls;
    URLRunnable(BlockingQueue<String> urls) { this.urls = urls; }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String url = null;
        while((url = urls.poll()) != null) {
            // do something with url
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will submit the same set of URLs 30 times, but maybe that's exactly what OP wanted. No problem since each URL will be processed only once, just not intuitive.